# Django DateTimeField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a field in my model

```
    published_on = models.DateTimeField()
```

on a Django template page and I want to show only the date instead of date along with time. Any idea how to truncate the time form date in the django model form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the date filter in your template, for instance:

```
{{ form.published_on|date:"D d M Y" }}
```

Or just:

```
{{ form.published_on|date }}
```

You can customize the output the way you want, or use the locale default. See [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#std:templatefilter-date) for details.

Comment: i am using django ModelForm and i want to truncate the value from      {{form.published_on}}

Comment: So simply apply the filter to that field, like {{form.published_on|date}}. I updated the answer.

Comment: How about {{ form.published_on.date|date }} ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to set a different input format for your field: published_on = models.DateTimeField(input_formats=["%d/%M"])

Comment: @pojo, @user1118780, `{{ form.published_on }}` would render a form input field. The date filter will have no effect here. Perhaps the OP wants to not show the time *input box* ?

Comment: @YujiTomita Yes, you are probably right about that. To be fair, the question was not very clear :-)

Comment: @pojo, I agree, the question isn't clear at all. You still can't use a date filter on a form field though! `{{ form.published_on.value|date }}` would work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `SplitDateTimeWidget` to represent the field in two widgets (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#splitdatetimewidget). Then, for example, the time field could be hidden with CSS. This method is particularly useful if you need to preserve the actual time value, and just allow user to change the date.